# Auto closing brackets in visual-studio-code not working for js and jsx files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsx

I am using vscode and it adds a closing bracket or parenthesis if you add the opening bracket or parenthesis but while I use js files or JSX files it doesn't add the closing pair.

##### Please answer how to fix this issue

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer

Comment: @Matt It is not working. vscode is not auto closing the brackets

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add:

```
"[javascriptreact]": {"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"}
```

for JSX files

and

```
"[javascript]": {"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"}
```

for js files

in the settings.json