# Auto closing brackets stopped working in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

As I was using editor normally, it suddenly stopped closing all paired things `( ), [ ], { }`. It no longer works in JS and Python, maybe in other languages too. Quotes `' ', " "` still work.

I tried to reopen or open new files, relaunch editor, set `"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"` - nothing worked.

Setting it specifically for JS files worked for `.js`, but general rule is not working still.

What could have happened and how to fix it?

UPD: It appears to be already reported as bug [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127739).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto closing brackets in visual-studio-code not working for js and jsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68228477/auto-closing-brackets-in-visual-studio-code-not-working-for-js-and-jsx-files)

Comment: @GinoMempin for some reason doing it for one specific language worked, but applying `"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"` to general setting did not.